# Can two singularities combine into one?

Tags: black-hole, singularity, collision

We know that black holes can collide and merge, but if they each have a singularity at the core, how can the two singularities merge and become one? Wouldn't the mere fact of a second singularity in range of another make it not a singularity?

Comment: Its best not to think of the singularity as a "thing" that is inside the black hole at a particular position. It is a point in spacetime (not a point in space), and it is a point that is always in the future.

Comment: This [has been asked before](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13809/24157) but I'm not particularly convinced of the answer there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do black hole singularities actually merge?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/do-black-hole-singularities-actually-merge)

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically, Yes. Realistically, No. As James mentioned a singularity isn't a physical object but rather a point in space time. In theory a wormhole is just two singularities which combined.